# Xunit plugin (Junit) in Jenkins shows every test case as passed while this is not the case

Tags: jenkins, junit

Xunit plugin has no troubles reading the `xml` file but considers every case as passed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites errors="0" failures="1" disabled="" name="Processing.lvproj" tests="1" time="216">
  <testsuite tests="3" time="216" name="Bad pixel correction.vi" failures="1" errors="0" timestamp="1/01/1904 1:00:00" id="0" hostname="jenkins" skipped="0" disabled="">
    <testcase name="Test Case 1" classname="0" status="Failed" time="124" assertions=""/>
    <testcase name="Test Case 2" classname="0" status="Passed" time="59" assertions=""/>
    <testcase name="Test Case 3" classname="0" status="Passed" time="33" assertions=""/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This clearly shows that the status of the first test case is "Failed"
I have tried many different things but nothing seems to work. Does somebody have an idea?